# Argument vanishes in the middle of the method?

Tags: java, arraylist

Whenever I run this method the print goes perfectly fine so the argument is passed and not null. Still it gives a NullPointerException when the argument is added to the children ArrayList (which is a part of the class). Why is this?

```
public void addChild(_Node n){
    System.out.println("Add " + n.getClass().getSimpleName() + " to " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    children.add(n);
}
```

Comment: I'm a C++ programmer, but are you sure that `children` is not null? Try commenting out that `children.add(n);` line and see if it still gives the same exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if `children` has been instantiated correctly. This is a common mistake beginners make.

Comment: Ah I see, I'm still used to an other language.
 
Thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 3):

> NullPointerException when the argument
>   is added to the children ArrayList

`children` is null.

`n` is not null and you can add null objects to most Lists.